# python pandas groupby to identify rows

Tags: python, pandas

I used to clean data using SAS but I would like to switch to Python.

I had a large dataset which was scrapped from some filings (html) but included some noisy information and I would like to get rid of these irrelevant data.

Basically, I need to remove certain rows of data after a row with condition being True (however, this might be a list, multiple True/or no True at all; and if there are Trues, I want to identify the last one).

Raw data:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Report_ID</td>
    <td>Table_ID</td>
    <td>Group_ID</td>
    <td>Item_ID</td>
    <td>Flag_old</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>item4</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>item5</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>item4</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>item4</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Expected data:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Report_ID</td>
    <td>Table_ID</td>
    <td>Group_ID</td>
    <td>Item_ID</td>
    <td>Flag_old</td>
    <td>Flag_new</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>    
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>item4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>item5</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>item4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>item3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>item4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see from the above, I wanted to identify rows below the rows with condition Flag_old == 1.

Given the structure of the data, I have firstly use groupby to segment my whole dataframe and I was thinking to define a function to select rows and apply the function to the dataframe groupby object and then of course create a new column for the whole dataframe indicating these rows of noisy data.

```
def lastline(series):
    return max(series[series.values == 1].index)

df['lastline'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lastline(df['flag']))
```

but I got `'int' object is not callable` error.

Could you please advice me how to do this properly? I have been struggling with this for few days now...Many thanks.

Comment: Did you call a variable somewhere else in your script `lastline` or `max`? Difficult to know, what's going on  without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Share a sample of your data and the expected output

Comment: @AndreyF, thanks both, I will produce a sample data.

Comment: @Piinthesky, no I didn't call them. I will generate a sample data in a min so you guys will see what I wanted to do with my data. Many thanks again.

Comment: @AndreyF in this case, I only get rows with flag_old == 1 right? but I wanted to have the rows below identified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need custom function with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return new column:

```
def f(x):
    #get cumulative sum, shift
    a = x.cumsum().shift()
    #check max value of cumsumed a and chain condition for remove 0 only groups
    #convert Trues to 1 by astype
    return ((a == a.max()) & (a != 0)).astype(int)

df['Flag_new'] = df.groupby('Group_ID')['Flag_old'].transform(f)
print (df)
   Report_ID  Table_ID  Group_ID Item_ID  Flag_old  Flag_new
0          A         1         1   item1         0         0
1          A         1         1   item2         0         0
2          A         1         1   item3         1         0
3          A         1         1   item4         0         1
4          A         1         1   item5         0         1
5          A         1         2   item1         1         0
6          A         1         2   item2         0         0
7          A         1         2   item3         1         0
8          A         1         2   item4         0         1
9          A         1         3   item1         0         0
10         A         1         3   item2         0         0
11         A         1         3   item3         0         0
12         A         1         3   item4         0         0
```

Comment: many thanks, would it be possible for a bit more details? My understanding  for your function is that: create an array filled with zeros, but I don't understand the followings...

Comment: Do you think `a[-1] = x.max()` ? `a[-1]` is for selecting last value of array `a` and `a[-1] = x.max()` assign max value of x to last value.

Comment: thanks! May I ask what if there are two rows after the row with 'Flag_old' ==1? The issue I was struggling with is to select rows after a row with the last flag. Many thanks again.

Comment: Sure, but not sure if undestand. My solution for each  get max value of `Flag_old` per group and assign to last value. Is it what you need? I add blank rows to output df for better seen groups.

Comment: @Jin - Or need check last previous values for 1 per groups, rows with indices `2,6,10` ?

Comment: for instance, in the first panel of the output, we have another item5 and its also below item3 (which has value =1 for flag_old). I wanted to identify both item4 and item5 in this case.

Comment: jezrael, please check out my revised html tables with a new-added item5, many thanks, again.

Comment: I test if first value is `1` and `bfill()` has to be removed.

Comment: I was trying to add an extra condition: if the first value of the array `Flag_old` equals to 1 then `Flag_new` should be all zeros. I tried to put a if statement in the custom function (`if x[0] == 1 and x.sum() ==1: a = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(x))) return (a != 0).astype(int) else: a = x.cumsum().shift() return ....`, it works fine with a list as an example. But when I put the function in my main dataset,  `KeyError 0` showed up.

Comment: I think you need select first value by position by `iat` -  `if x.iat[0] == 1 and x.sum() ==1:`

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little complicated for a one-liner with `apply` but you can use:

```
df['flag_new'] = df.groupby("Group_ID").apply(lambda g_df: [0]* len(g_df['Flag_old']) if g_df['Flag_old'].sum() == 0 else [0]* (len(g_df['Flag_old'])-1) +[1]).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

or you can use `transform`:

```
df['flag_new'] = df.groupby("Group_ID")['flag'].transform(lambda x: [0]* len(x) if x.sum() == 0 else [0]* (len(x)-1) +[1])
```

In both cases the output will be:

```
   Report_ID  Table_ID  Group_ID Item_ID  Flag_old  Flag_new
0          A         1         1   item1         0         0
1          A         1         1   item2         0         0
2          A         1         1   item3         1         0
3          A         1         1   item4         0         1
4          A         1         2   item1         1         0
5          A         1         2   item2         0         0
6          A         1         2   item3         1         0
7          A         1         2   item4         0         1
8          A         1         3   item1         0         0
9          A         1         3   item2         0         0
10         A         1         3   item3         0         0
11         A         1         3   item4         0         0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, AndreyF! I wanted to identify the rows after the row with "Flag_old" == 1. In my data, it is not necessary that those will be the last row, for instance, can be multiple rows? Could you please advice me how to  deal with this? I was thinking about comparing with index of these rows...